# get specification of executed gem from within

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have build a gem and want it to print its version.

I cant use `Gem::Specification.find_by_name('mygem').version`
because there are several versions of it installed.

Lets just say my program has just a single src file /bin/myruby containing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby 
mygem_version = ???
puts "This is my gems version: #{mygem_version}"
```

Comment: my own one. I want it to print its version.

Comment: Can you show us the code of the gem?

Comment: what part would you need? lets say it has a binary with /bin/mygem with just a single line of code puts "mygem-version#{Gem::Spec..}".

Comment: What's the context for "current version". The version you have loaded/required?  If so, `MyGem::VERSION` should be good for a standard gem - and if it is not, you can always arrange for it to be so for your *own* gems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common convention is to create a `lib/<your_gem_name>/version.rb` that defines a `YourGemName::VERSION` constant. Then, you can refer to that constant *in* your `gemspec`, which is Ruby code that gets evaluated when the gem is built.

Read http://timelessrepo.com/making-ruby-gems for a guide that uses this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Bundler` (think `rails`), try

```
Bundler.definition.specs
```

else, make sure your gem has a VERSION constant you can ask these things

Comment: sorry, i dont use bundler/rails.

Comment: then add `VERSION` constant :) it's convention to do so anyway

Comment: but its not dynamic i would have to raise it on my own along with the version in spec. I use Gem.loaded_specs['mygem'].version now.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and always returned the correct version.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby 
puts "This is my gems version: #{Gem.loaded_specs['mygem'].version}"
```

Comment: This does not work if it’s your own gems; it only works for gems you’ve loaded for the project.

Comment: @Smar actually, this is somewhat false. You can ask for your own gem see where 'mygem' is being passed to `Gem.loaded_specs`? Replace this with the name of your gem (that you're "inside" of). Tricky part is "dynamically" knowing the gem name 